# Conduct DBSCAN on radian distance matrix with sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, data-mining

I wish to conduct clustering on several timestamps(in minutes).
So what i've done so far is:

1) Convert points to radian

```
#points containing time value in minutes
points = [100, 200, 600, 659, 700]

def convert_to_radian(x):
    return((x / (24 * 60)) * 2 * pi)

rad_function = np.vectorize(convert_to_radian)
points_rad = rad_function(points)
```

2) Generate distance matrix

```
#generate distance matrix from each point
dist = points_rad[None,:] - points_rad[:, None]
```

3) Assign shortest distances from each point

```
dist[((dist > pi) & (dist <= (2*pi)))] = dist[((dist > pi) & (dist <= (2*pi)))] -(2*pi)
dist[((dist > (-2*pi)) & (dist <= (-1*pi)))] = dist[((dist > (-2*pi)) & (dist <= (-1*pi)))] + (2*pi) 
dist = abs(dist)
```

And now i want to use DBSCAN on the distance matrix, how do i go about clustering it to radian distance?

Thank you!

Comment: I think your distance matrix isn't a distance matrix.

Comment: Why do you want to convert a simple linear measurement into an angle? (BTW, most clocks have 12 hrs on the dial, not 24)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse it is! i managed to figure it out!

Comment: @TomMorris I wanted to differentiate between say 9am and 9pm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so after much digging i realized that i could simply just set DBSCAN metric to 'precomputed', use the `.fit()` method and pass in my distance matrix. For those that are interested here is the source:

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

#points containing time value in minutes
points = [100, 200, 600, 659, 700]

def convert_to_radian(x):
    return((x / (24 * 60)) * 2 * pi)

rad_function = np.vectorize(convert_to_radian)
points_rad = rad_function(points)

#generate distance matrix from each point
dist = points_rad[None,:] - points_rad[:, None]

#Assign shortest distances from each point
dist[((dist > pi) & (dist <= (2*pi)))] = dist[((dist > pi) & (dist <= (2*pi)))] -(2*pi)
dist[((dist > (-2*pi)) & (dist <= (-1*pi)))] = dist[((dist > (-2*pi)) & (dist <= (-1*pi)))] + (2*pi) 
dist = abs(dist)

#check dist
print(dist)

#using default values, set metric to 'precomputed'
db = DBSCAN(eps=((100 / (24*60)) * 2 * pi ), min_samples = 2, metric='precomputed')

#check db
print(db)

db.fit(dist)

#get labels
labels = db.labels_

#get number of clusters
no_clusters = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)

print('No of clusters:', no_clusters)
print('Cluster 0 : ', np.nonzero(labels == 0)[0])
print('Cluster 1 : ', np.nonzero(labels == 1)[0])
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.          0.43633231  2.18166156  2.43909763  2.61799388]
 [ 0.43633231  0.          1.74532925  2.00276532  2.18166156]
 [ 2.18166156  1.74532925  0.          0.25743606  0.43633231]
 [ 2.43909763  2.00276532  0.25743606  0.          0.17889625]
 [ 2.61799388  2.18166156  0.43633231  0.17889625  0.        ]]

DBSCAN(algorithm='auto', eps=0.4363323129985824, leaf_size=30,
metric='precomputed', min_samples=2, p=None, random_state=None)

No of clusters: 2
Cluster 0 :  [0 1]
Cluster 1 :  [2 3 4]
```